# FMX TStringGrid set selected cell

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, tstringgrid

I need to do a cell jump in an FMX `TStringGrid`. Before, I did it in a VCL application using this code:

```pascal
StringGrid.Row := StringGrid.Row + 1;
StringGrid.Col := 1;
```

So, how do I do that in FMX?

Comment: Take a [tour] and find out how to not make your question appear that sloppy (linebreaks and missing formatting). You might want to add [the tag "TStringGrid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tstringgrid). Also commas instead of correct punctuation can change the sense drastically.

Answer (score 2):

If you tried the same code in FMX, you might have been misguided by the fact that FMX doesn't indicate the selection automatically. You need to set the focus to the grid to see which cell is selected:

```
StringGrid1.Row := StringGrid1.Row+1;
StringGrid1.Col := 1;
StringGrid1.SetFocus;
```

Alternatively you can select a cell also with

```
StringGrid1.SelectCell(1, 2); // col, row
StringGrid1.SetFocus;
```

Answer (score 0):

The *exact* same code should work in FMX too, as FMX's [`TStringGrid`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TStringGrid) has writable [`Row`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.Row) and [`Col`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.Col) properties, just like VCL's `TStringGrid` has.